# How to determine next activity assignee in workflow in tridion

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am writing eventhandler for determining the workflow activities. I am able to get the currrent activity assignee.

I need to get the next activity assignee(i.e to which group the activity is assigned to).

Inside the TridionActivityDefinitinData for NextActivityDefinitions i find only Title and Idref of the activities.

Please let me know how to find the next possible activities' assignee.

Comment: Did you have a look at this question and the answers? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274816/how-to-get-the-next-activity-details-from-the-finishactivityevent-hanlder

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at this question [How to get the Next Activity Details from the FinishActivityEvent Hanlder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274816/), where user978511 answered it there better than I can.

From what I see there, you'll need something like this:

```
FinishActivityEventArgs.ActivityFinish.NextAssignee
```

If that is indeed the case, I marked your question as a duplicate from that one.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps someone...

Read the Process Definition for the full list of activities:

```
ProcessDefinitionData pdd = CoreServiceClient.Read(ProcessInstance.ProcessDefinition.IdRef, null) as ProcessDefinitionData;
```

then you can use your current posostion (not zero based) to index out from the Activitiy Definitions (zero based):

```
pdd.ActivityDefinitions[(int)ActivityInstance.Position].Assignee.Title
```

The above will get you the next activity information. If you want previous activities start by subtracting two from the current position and indexing from the Process Instance Activities:

```
ProcessInstance.Activities[(int)ActivityInstance.Position - 2].FinishMessage
```

Enjoy